# Big-O: Prove $2^n$ is $O(n!)$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I am a little stuck trying to prove that $2^n$ is $O(n!)$. Obviously, I can tell in a few ways that this is the case. For one, based on Big-$O$ hierarchy, the exponential is beneath the factorial in terms of complexity. I also substituted $C = 2$ and tried several values of $n$, all following the Big-$O$ definition of $f(n) \le cg(n)$.

However, my professor says neither of these is a sufficient justification and I should be able to use the definition alone.

How can I do this? I know in the past it has been advantageous for me to compare the functions by converting one into a form that resembles the other, but I just can't figure out how to relate the factorial and $2^n$ functions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7):

We have 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!} = e^2 < \infty, 
$$
hence $2^n/n! \to 0$. This means $2^n = O(n!)$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 5):

Can you show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n!}=0\text{ ?}$$

**Hint** $$\frac{2^n}{n!}=\frac{2}{1}\frac{2}{2}\frac{2}{3}\cdots\frac{2}{n-1}\frac{2}{n}$$

so as soon as $n\geq 4$, this is

$$\frac{2^n}{n!}\leq \frac{2}{1}\frac{2}{2}\cdot1\cdots 1\cdot \frac{2}{n}=\frac{4}{n}$$

Then choose, say, $\epsilon =1$..

**ADD** Let $a_n=2^n,b_n=n!$. Then showing $$a_n\leq C\cdot b_n$$ eventually is equivalent to showing $$\log a_n\leq \log C+\log b_n$$ eventually, that is $$n\log 2\leq \log C+\log n!$$

In the left hand side, we sum $\log 2$ $n$ times, while on the right hand side we sum $\log 2,\log 3,\dots$ and so on. This is essentially the idea I gave before: in one, the product is fixed: one always multiplies by $2$; while in the other the factors grow without bound.

Comment: That justification also makes sense to me, but it is insisted that I use the definition and compare the functions. I thought about taking the logarithm, but I don't think that would help considering the factorial.

Hmm, the expansion does look promising, though! I think I'll at least try it that way and see what the verdict is.

Comment: @user2395694 : By taking the definition, do you mean showing that there exists $C$ such that $2^n \le C (n!) \, $? Because the reason we keep showing that $2^n/n! \to 0$ in the other answers is because a convergent sequence is bounded, hence $2^n/n! \le C$ for some constant $C$, thus showing that $2^n/n!$ converges is enough. Is that the point that you were lacking?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{2^n}{n!}}=\frac{2^{n+1}n!}{2^n(n+1)!}=\frac2{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_n=\frac{2^n}{n!}$ then by ratio test we have
$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{2}{n+1}\to_\infty 0$$
hence the sequence $(u_n)$ is convergent to $0$ and then we find that $2^n=O(n!)$ and more precisely $2^n=o(n!)$

Comment: Slow day today, it seems.